# Which is correct between cover or covering?

Tags: covering-spaces

Let $I$ be closed n-dimensional intervals,
$$I=\{\mathbf{x}: a_j\le x_j \le b_j, \quad j=1, \cdots, n\}$$

and $S$ be a countable collection of intervals $I_k$,
$$S=\{I_j,\quad j=1, 2, \cdots\}$$

In this case, if $\displaystyle E\subset\cup_{I_j\in S}I_j$, $S$ is a _____ of $E$.

covering or cover?

My professor said us covering, but wikipedia said us cover.
Which is correct?

Comment: It doesn't help much, but I think that both are acceptable.  I would say "a covering of $E$" or a "cover for $E$" (note the different prepositions).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you, I edited

Comment: Both are correct with proposition "of".